# bootstrap datetimepicker retuns a string, how to convert this string into datetime (php)

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, datetime

I have a bootstrap [datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) in a form with method POST.

In my Symfony2.7 application, I revover the `$_POST['date']` like this:

```
$startDate = $this->get('request')->request->get('date');
```

I need this data to be a datetime, and only a datetime in order to use this in a doctrine dql. But when I make a `var_dump($startDate);` it returns me a string:

```
string '25/08/2015 00:00' (length=16)
```

Is there a way to convert this string into Datetime?

I try the method `DateTime::createFromFormat` but it retuns me false, of course because `$startDate` is a string.

There is my html code:

```
<div class='input-group date datePicker'>
    <input type="datetime" class="form-control" id="startDate" name="date" required="required"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // load bootstrap datetimepicker
    $(function () {
        $('.datePicker').datetimepicker({
            locale: 'fr',
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: use `DateTime` as an instance (`$datetime = new DateTime($startDate);`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `DateTime` as instance might do the trick. Its constructor deal with the string format.

`$datetime = new DateTime($startDate);`

And, as you stated in comments, replace the slashes before it:

```
str_replace('/', '-', $startDate)
```